# SQL merge rows with same ID to one

Tags: sql-server, merge, grouping

Currently I have the following table:

```
ID                                      Date        Number
-------------------------------------------------------
F78D56A2-5BF1-4172-90BA-23CAF6A05A10    NULL        NULL
F78D56A2-5BF1-4172-90BA-23CAF6A05A10    NULL        NULL
F78D56A2-5BF1-4172-90BA-23CAF6A05A10    NULL        001234
F78D56A2-5BF1-4172-90BA-23CAF6A05A10    2018-11-30  NULL
```

The requested output is:

```
ID                                      Date        Number
-------------------------------------------------------
F78D56A2-5BF1-4172-90BA-23CAF6A05A10    2018-11-30  001234
```

Ofcourse you cant use `group by` since that requires more arguments. How could I do this?

Comment: Select ID, MAX(DATE), MAX(NUMBER) FROM Your table Group by ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try JOIN to avoid GROUP BY

```
SELECT T1.Id, MAX(T1.Date) AS Date, MAX(T1.Number) As Number
FROM YourTableName AS T1
JOIN YourTableName AS T2 ON T1.column_name = T2.column_name;
```